# How to bind local JSON Model to MultiComboBox in SAPUI5?

Tags: json, combobox, binding, model, sapui5

how can I bind my local JSON model to my MultiComboBox.
The XML code for the combobox is looking as followed:

```
<MultiComboBox id="multiBox" selectionFinish="onBoxFinish"/>
```

The model looks like this:

```
var exampleData = {
            "data": [{
                "name": "Example1",
                "value": "16.505406"
            },
            {
                "name": "Example2",
                "value": "6.65465"
            },
            {
                "name": "Example3",
                "value": "89.56456"
            }]  
        };
```

I want to display the 3 names in the ComboBox.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, instantiate a [JSONModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel) with your data. Secondly, set the JSONModel to your view. Thirdly, bind the model to your [MultiComboBox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MultiComboBox).

```
var oData = {
    "data": [
        {
             "name": "Example1",
             "value": "16.505406"
        },
        {
             "name": "Example2",
             "value": "6.65465"
        },
        {
            "name": "Example3",
            "value": "89.56456"
        }
    ]  
};

var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
this.getView().setModel(oModel);

<MultiComboBox
    selectionFinish="onBoxFinish"
    items="{/data}">
    <core:Item 
        key="{name}" 
        text="{value}">
    </core:Item>
</MultiComboBox>
```